# Simulation of TX/RX Drop

Tags: iptables, netstat, iperf

I'm trying to get the "TX/RX Drop" values to increase.

I've tried dropping packets using both *iperf* and *iptables* but the statistics aren't increasing even when packets are being dropped.

Is there a way of getting these values to increase? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dave, can you provide more information?  Are you wanting to simulate a network condition to cause a TX/RX Drop value on a switch port?

One common cause of a TX/RX Drop value climbing is incorrect speed and duplex settings on the point to point ports.  If one port is set to 100 Full, but the other is set to 10 Half, you will have packets dropped simultaneously on both ports in opposite directions.

Comment: It's on a Linux machine. Basically, I'd like a way to cause packets to drop for testing purposes.

Comment: Here is another post that explains the linux tools to help you achieve your goal.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux